# Position text and image independently of each other

Tags: html, css

I need to position each element of my HTML independently to each other i.e. each element should be able to have each own top and left margin. Setting the margin for an element should not impact or change the margin/positioning of any other element. The html is pasted in an email as a signature, so if a user inserts a line above the elements, they should however move down in unison. I have tried divs with positions and margins to no avail - it seems the first element always impacts the position of the second element. Please help!

Comment: I have made hundreds of email hmtl signature. You will possibly find out that the best practive for email signatures are tables.

Comment: And a sample of the HTML that you'd like to style..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by making an image the first element in the html. Further elements like

can then be positioned by using the position:relative and margin properties. Simply subtract the image height from the top margin of the first text element. Using this technique, text can even be positioned above an image.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is e-mail, I would try using tables.  I know tables are frowned upon for layout, but there are so many e-mail clients out there you really want to use the simplest markup possible so it just works and forget about semantics.

You might also want to look at example templates used by e-mail services like MailChimp, and see how they do it.  Chances are those are tried and tested solutions that work.

Comment: unfortunately tables is not an option, i really need to be able to set the left and top margins of elements exactly

Comment: an image might be the best option, there is full control of its contents.  there is not exact control over layout in e-mail clients, each one has its layout quirks